# Using class set in media query as mixin in less

Tags: css, less, media-queries

I am trying to reuse a set of classes set inside a media query as mixins to use throughout a website instead of embedding un-semantic class names in html.

Here is an example of my problem.

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {

    .foo{width:120px;}
    .foo-2{width:150px;}
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {

    .foo{width:110px;}
    .foo-2{width:120px;}
}

.bar{.foo;}
.bar-2{.foo;}
.bar-3{.foo-2;}
```

the .bar-X will never get any styles applied. I can guess that this is happening because LESS doesn't create .bar-X inside media queries, so nothing will ever be applied.

Is this a bug in LESS, or something I can never achieve? A workaround to this would be ideal.

Comment: What about declaring .foo above the media queries section, then the media queries will override the attributes and it will fall down throw to your bar-X selectors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is a common misconception. LESS does not *process* the `@media` query, the browser does *after LESS has done its work*. LESS can only *create the CSS code* that the browser is going to read. So the `@media` is "meaningless" to LESS, it is just like any other selector (`.someClass div table`, etc.), it only processes what the `@media` is going to serve to the browser.

So that means you need to put all your code that changes for the `@media` in the `@media` block. But you also don't want a bunch of repeated code. So instead, create a master mixin to set your `@media` code, and then call that mixin from the media queries:

```
.makeFooGroup(@w1, @w2) {
    .foo {width: @w1}
    .foo-2{width: @w2}
    .bar{.foo}
    .bar-2{.foo}
    .bar-3{.foo-2}
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .makeFooGroup(120px, 150px);
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
    .makeFooGroup(110px, 120px);
}
```

Produces this css:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .foo {width: 120px;}
  .foo-2 {width: 150px;}
  .bar {width: 120px;}
  .bar-2 {width: 120px;}
  .bar-3 {width: 150px;}
}
@media (max-width: 999px) {
  .foo {width: 110px;}
  .foo-2 {width: 120px;}
  .bar {width: 110px;}
  .bar-2 {width: 110px;}
  .bar-3 {width: 120px;}
}
```

For some further info I've given on LESS and `@media` related to this, see:

1. [CSS pre-processor with a possibility to define variables in a @media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139067/css-pre-processor-with-a-possibility-to-define-variables-in-a-media-query/14142709#14142709)
2. [Media Query grouping instead of multiple scattered media queries that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503862/media-query-grouping-instead-of-multiple-scattered-media-queries-that-match/13617917#13617917)

Comment: Great answer, I am just going to try it now. I had assumed the problem was with LESS not "being clever" with media queries and understanding what one was trying to achieve. I was hoping that LESS was smart enough to create all of the statements which reference a media query in a media query itself without the user having to.

Comment: Just set this up and is working exactly as I wanted. I added a few mixins inside the "makeFooGroup" mixin to dynamically create the widths based on desired parameters which works perfectly. The only downside is whenever I want to setup gridwork it needs to be done within this mixin main, but this could be seen as a positive as it forces all major gridwork to be viewable in one area. Thank you so much.