# LESS: access class inside media query as mixin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, media-queries

Suppose there's a declaration like this (it's Bootstrap actually):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to access .navbar inside this media query (it also has a declaration outsides it) as any other class or mixin? I'd like to re-use its declarations somewhere else (well, not exactly this one but you get the idea :-)), e.g.:

```
.left-nav {
    .navbar; // Use the one from the media query here.
}
```

Is this possible with LESS?

I've seen a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384029/using-class-set-in-media-query-as-mixin-in-less), although the difference here is that I can't refactor 
`.navbar` to be outside the media query since this is in Bootstrap's LESS file. I understand hat LESS doesn't care about media queries because they are just another type of selector; but how can you access declarations inside these selectors (I tried some obvious ones but neither worked).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way that you can except from *within* the `@media` itself, for example:

**This LESS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .left-nav {
    .navbar; // Use the one from the media query here.
  }
}

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**Produces this CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .left-nav {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

I'm fairly certain that is *not* what you are wanting to do.

However, I believe that since the `@media` is not itself a selector (it is a query string to the browser), then it cannot be accessed of itself either as a mixin or as a namespace in LESS, and therefore its contents are inaccessible in the way you desire.

If I'm wrong, I hope someone posts an answer otherwise--but I'm not expecting it.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is not what I'm looking for. I do hope somebody shows up with a hidden LESS gem :-).

Answer (score -1):

@media is actually interpreted as a LESS variable when using LESS. If it hasn't been declared as anything then it won't work, but you can use it as a LESS variable that is set to the native CSS meaning with a literal string, so as a LESS variable I have @media set like this:

```
@media: "@media";
```

then I can use @media more like I would expect with native css, eg:

```
.random-widget {
    height: 100px;    
    @media (min-width: @screen-sm) {         
        height: 300px;
    }  
}
```

Comment: "@media is actually interpreted as a LESS variable" - That's not correct. Your example is actually perfectly valid LESS code that compiles as expected without any `@media: "@media";`(you can test it [here](http://less2css.org) or [here](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)).