# Break out of scope

Tags: css, less, media-queries, dry

Ideally, I would like to do this :

```
@w: 4px;

@media (max-width:900px) {
    @r: 3px; 
}
@media (min-width:900px) {
    @r: 5px; 
}

.myclass {
    border-radius: @w + @r;
}
```

This doesn't compile because `@r` isn't defined in the scope where I define `.myclass`. The obvious solutions are either to define `.myclass` inside the `@media` blocs or to copy the `@media` queries inside the definition of `.myclass`.

But as soon as you use `@r` in many classes, both solutions are messy and involve many duplications.

Is there a clean dry solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a mixin, that calculates the property values according to the mediaquery. It is unnecessary to do this via import.

**LESS:**

```
@w: 4px;
.bordermixin(@w,@r) {
  .myclass{
    border-radius: @w + @r;
  }
}
@media (max-width:900px) {
    .bordermixin(@w,3px);
}
@media (min-width:900px) {
    .bordermixin(@w,5px);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .myclass{
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .myclass{
    border-radius: 9px;
  }
}
```

Comment: another note: if you define @w before the mixin (globally) ... then you dont even need 2 arguments and could just use .bordermixin(@r) and the global @w would be used in the calculation.

Comment: +1 This is a good solution (if not repeating @w in the declaration). It could be painful if there were more than 3 or 4 variables to pass but in my case it's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, based on `@import`, which lets me keep dry.

I make two files :

**classes.less**

```
@w: 4px;

.myclass {
    border-radius: @w + @r;
}
```

**mediawidth.less**

```
@media (max-width:900px) {
    @r: 3px; 
    @import "classes.less";
}
@media (min-width:900px) {
    @r: 5px; 
    @import "classes.less";
}
```

**Generated CSS :**

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .myclass {
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .myclass {
    border-radius: 9px;
  }
}
```

This way I don't have to repeat the many classes definition but only the import.

---

I accepted Martin's answer, which is much cleaner in the most common case when there are only a few numbers of variables to pass. My solution might be dryer and cleaner as soon as you have more variables and when your classes are defined in many files.