# LESS calculations with media queries in mixins

Tags: less, media-queries, mixins

I have a LESS mixin like so:

```
  .ico-space(@times){
    @ico-space: ((25px + 38px) * @times) - 1px;
    @media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
      @ico-space: ((25px + 38px) * @times) - 1px + 65px;
    }
  }
```

However, it doesn't pick up the calculations within the media query.
Probably I'm doing something wrong here, since I'm pretty new to using advance LESS features?

Comment: Are you trying to assign a different value to the variable based on the media query? If yes, I don't think this way would work because Less doesn't really evaluate media queries. It would just output them. You would probably be better off using guards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS CSS set variables in media query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906114/less-css-set-variables-in-media-query)